# How to make my SVG map render correctly in the browser?

Tags: html, css, svg, maps, geography

I want a dynamic webpage that looks nearly identical to this one that is for sale:

[image]

So I bought and implemented the [US state map](http://0.s3.envato.com/files/55289841/advanced/map.html) but it's becoming too small on my webpage:
[image]

I want the map to be larger. How can it be done? The [entire code](http://pastebin.com/wanDa5L3) is large so I've taken out the relevant part that displays the map and I've taken out all the SVG data from this code block

```
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-IN" class="js"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">


    <meta name="keywords" content="Houses Apartments, Vacation homes, Offices, Land, Flatmates,Paying Guest, Other real estate, Cars, Motorcycles, Accessories  parts, Trucks, Other vehicles, Home  Garden, Clothing, For Kids (Toys  Clothes), Jewelry  Watches, Hobbies, Sports  Bicycles, Movies, Books  Magazines, Pets, Tickets, Art  Collectibles, Music  Instruments, Computers  Accessories, TV, Audio, Video, Cameras, Cellphones  gadgets, Video games  consoles, Job offers, Resumes, Services, Classes, Professional,Office equipment, Other,  ">
    <meta name="description" content="Find jobs, cars, houses, mobile phones and properties for sale in your region conveniently. Find the best deal among {{count}} free ads online!"> 


    <title>Free classifieds in India - HipHeap.com</title>
    <!-- CSS INCLUDES: -->
                      <link href="/static/india_files/index_in.css?234" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">   
    <!--[if lt IE 9.]>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="http://content.hipheap.com/js/3e233f78542ce91af211f0d166/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->



<link rel="icon" href="/img/favicon_in.ico?07217" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon_in.ico?07217" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="/img/favicon_in.png?07217" type="image/png">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon_in.png?07217" type="image/png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/img/favicon_ios_in.png?07217" type="image/png">


    <link rel="prerender" href="/"> 
    <link rel="prefetch" href="/"> 

    <!-- JAVASCRIPTS: -->
                 </script><script type="text/javascript" src="/static/1_files/jquery-1.js"></script> <link href="/static/css/index_usa.css?978923487" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="icon" href="/img/favicon_us.ico?51340" type="image/x-icon">

<link href="/static/1_files/common_us.css?9823476" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/theCss.css" />
    <script src="/static/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/static/us2Config.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/static/theJava.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            addEvent('map_1');
            addEvent('map_2');
            addEvent('map_3');
            addEvent('map_4');
            addEvent('map_5');
            addEvent('map_6');
            addEvent('map_7');
            addEvent('map_8');
            addEvent('map_9');
            addEvent('map_10');
            addEvent('map_11');
            addEvent('map_12');
            addEvent('map_13');
            addEvent('map_14');
            addEvent('map_15');
            addEvent('map_16');
            addEvent('map_17');
            addEvent('map_18');
            addEvent('map_19');
            addEvent('map_20');
            addEvent('map_21');
            addEvent('map_22');
            addEvent('map_23');
            addEvent('map_24');
            addEvent('map_25');
            addEvent('map_26');
            addEvent('map_27');
            addEvent('map_28');
            addEvent('map_29');
            addEvent('map_30');
            addEvent('map_31');
            addEvent('map_32');
            addEvent('map_33');
            addEvent('map_34');
            addEvent('map_35');
            addEvent('map_36');
            addEvent('map_37');
            addEvent('map_38');
            addEvent('map_39');
            addEvent('map_40');
            addEvent('map_41');
            addEvent('map_42');
            addEvent('map_43');
            addEvent('map_44');
            addEvent('map_45');
            addEvent('map_46');
            addEvent('map_47');
            addEvent('map_48');
            addEvent('map_49');
            addEvent('map_50');
            addEvent('map_51');
        })
    </script>
    <style>
        .unselectable {
            -moz-user-select:none;
            -webkit-user-select:none;
        }
    </style>
    <style>
p.pos_fixed
{
position:fixed;
left:15px;
}
</style>         

</head>
<!--[if IE 6 ]> <body  name="body" class=" ie ie6 not-ie7 not-ie8 not-ie9 "> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]> <body  name="body" class=" ie ie7 not-ie6 not-ie8 not-ie9 "> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]> <body  name="body" class=" ie ie8 not-ie6 not-ie7 not-ie9 "> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]> <body  name="body" class=" ie ie9 not-ie6 not-ie7 not-ie8 "> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>--><body name="body" class=" not-ie6 not-ie7 not-ie8 not-ie9  not-ie"><!--<![endif]-->

    <div class="topbar">
        <div class="topbar-inner nohistory">
            <div class="topbar-left">
            <a class="topbar-new" href="https://www.hipheap.com/account/create"><strong>New!</strong> All your ads and saved searches in one place, create an account today!</a>

            </div>
            <div class="topbar-right">
                <a class="topbar-login last" href="https://www.hipheap.com/account/login" title="Login to your account" rel="nofollow">
                        <i class="sprite_common_topbar_log-in topbar-float_left"></i>
                        Log in  
                    </a>
                    <a class="topbar-create first" href="https://www.hipheap.com/account/create" title="Create your account" rel="nofollow">    
                        <i class="sprite_common_topbar_logged-in topbar-float_left"></i>
                        Create account      
                    </a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="wrapper">


    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <div class="alert-outer alert-error">
    <a href="#" class="alert-closer" title="close this alert" onclick="removeIeNotification(this); return false;">×</a>
    <div class="alert-inner">
        <span><strong>You are using an outdated version of Internet Explorer.</strong> For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade today!</span>

    </div>
</div>

    <![endif]-->
<header>
<h1 id="logo" class="sprite_index_in_in_en_logo spritetext">hipheap.com - The right choice for buying &amp; selling in india</h1>











    <div id="post">
 <a href="/ai" id="ad">Post your ad for free</a>

</div>




    </header>

<div class="main">
    <div class="column_left">
        <div class="box">
            <h2>High quality classifieds near you</h2>
<ul><li>HipHeap  is safe, easy, and free.</li>
<li>Buy and sell <a href="/india/cars-for_sale">cars</a>, check our <a href="/india/real_estate">real estate</a> section, find <a href="/india/jobs">jobs</a>, and much more.</li>
<li>Check our <strong><a href="/india">{{count}} ads online</a></strong> and find what you are looking for in your region or in all India.</li></ul>


    </div>

<div id="regions">      
        <div class="region_links_one">
            <ul class="regions_one">
                <li><a id="region_8" class="region" href="/q?query=regionID%3D4694186">Alabama</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_9" class="region" href="/q?query=regionID%3D4699188">Alaska</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_10" class="region" href="/q?query=regionID%3D4692186">California</a></li>

            </ul>
            <ul class="regions_two">
                <li><a id="region_22" class="region" href="/q?query=regionID%3D4694184">Kentucky</a></li>

                    </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="region_links_two">
            <h2>Union territories</h2>


























                <ul class="regions_one">
                <li><a class="region" href="/q?query=regionID%3D4699183">Delhi</a></li><li><a class="region" href="/q?query=regionID%3D4700189">Lakshadweep</a></li><li><a class="region" href="/q?query=regionID%3D4704183">Daman &amp; Diu</a></li><li><a class="region" href="/q?query=regionID%3D4691190">Dadra &amp; Nagar Haveli</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="regions_two">
                <li><a class="region" href="/q?query=regionID%3D4704183">Chandigarh</a></li><li><a class="region" href="/q?query=regionID%3D4676189">Pondicherry</a></li><li><a class="region" href="/q?query=regionID%3D4703187">Andaman &amp; Nicobar Islands</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

</div>

    </div>

<div id="mapcontainer">
    <!-- map code -->
    <div id="map_base">

    <span class="tip" id="tip"></span>
<div onselectstart="return false;" class="unselectable" >
<!-- the svg code starts here -->


</div>
</div>

<div id="likebtn">
    <iframe class="fb_iframe" tabindex="-1" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" src="./static/india_files/like.html"></iframe>
</div>



<div class="google_plus">
<!--[if gt IE 7]>
    <div id="google_plus1btn"><g:plusone size="medium" href="https://www.hipheap.com"></g:plusone></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.___gcfg = {lang: ''};
    (function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>

<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <div id="google_plus1btn"><div id="___plusone_0" style="text-indent: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: transparent; border-style: none; float: none; line-height: normal; font-size: 1px; vertical-align: baseline; display: inline-block; width: 90px; height: 20px; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"><iframe frameborder="0" hspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" style="position: static; top: 0px; width: 90px; margin: 0px; border-style: none; left: 0px; visibility: visible; height: 20px;" tabindex="0" vspace="0" width="100%" id="I0_137051343457799865" name="I0_13703434517799865" src="./static/india_files/fastbutton.html" allowtransparency="true" data-gapiattached="true" title="+1"></iframe></div></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.___gcfg = {lang: ''};
    (function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>

 <!--<![endif]-->
</div>


</div><footer class="nohistory columns">

            <div class="widecolumn">
<p class="first">A good deal is just around the corner!</p>



    <p>HipHeap is the right choice for safe buying and selling in India: a free classifieds website where you can buy and sell almost everything.</p>



    <p><a href="/ai">Post an ad for free</a> or browse through our categories. You will find thousands of free classifieds for cars, houses, mobile phones and gadgets, computers, pets and dozens of items and services in your state or union territory.</p>



    <p class="last"><strong>HipHeap does not charge any fee and does not require registration.</strong> Every ad is checked so we can give you the highest quality possible for the ads on our site. That’s why HipHeap is the most convenient, easiest to use and most complete free ads site in India.</p>











</div>
<aside>


    <nav class="navbar ">
        <a class="first" href="/customer_service.htm">
            <i class="sprite_common_customer_service"></i>
            <span>Customer Service</span>
        </a><!--
        <a href="/security/index.htm">
            <i class="sprite_common_security"></i>
            <span>Shop safely</span>
        </a>
        <a href="/rules.htm">
            <i class="sprite_common_rules"></i>
            <span>Rules</span>
        </a>
        <a href="/about.htm">
            <i class="sprite_common_about_footer_in"></i>
            <span>About HipHeap.com</span>
        </a>
        <a href="/copyright.htm">
            <i>©</i>
            <span>Kool Ventures</span>
        </a>-->
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/hipheap" target="_blank">
                <i class="sprite_common_facebook"></i> 
                <span>Follow us on Facebook</span>
            </a>


    </nav>


</aside>
<div id="world_sites">
    <p>
        Travelling abroad? Visit our classifieds sites in other countries. See:<br> 








            <a href="http://www.montao.com.br/" target="_blank">Montao</a>,  


    </p>
</div>


</footer>
<div id="scripts">
<!-- NO SCRIPTS --> 
</div>







</div><!-- / #wrapper  -->





</body></html>
```

I'm a newbie with SVG and the code is large and I acquired it so I'm not very familiar with what's implemented in the page, it's just supposed to be a selection of states on an HTML 5 map, so we got this SVG map that suits of requirements except that it's rendering too small. Can you give me a hint where I should change to make the efault rendering of the map larger? Is it the CSS or the HTML? The CSS that I acquired from the map's manuifacturer is:

```
/* reset */
form {display:block; margin:0; padding:0;} body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, hr, p, blockquote, /* structural elements structure element */dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, /* list elements list element */pre, /* text formatting elements text format element */fieldset, lengend, button, input, textarea, /* form elements  */th, td { /* table elements  */    margin: 0;    padding: 0;} table th,table td {padding:1px} /*  */body,button, input, select, textarea { /* for ie */    /*font: 12px/1 Tahoma, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;*/    font: 12px/1 arial,verdana,tahoma,sans-serif; /*  */}h1 { font-size: 18px; /* 18px / 12px = 1.5 */ }h2 { font-size: 16px; }h3 { font-size: 14px; }h4, h5, h6 { font-size: 100%; }address, cite, dfn, em, var { font-style: normal; } /*  */code, kbd, pre, samp, tt { font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace; } /*  */small { font-size: 12px; } /* *//*  */ul, ol { list-style: none; }/*  */a { text-decoration: none; color:#049;}a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }abbr[title], acronym[title] { /* ：1.ie6  abbr; 2.，ie6  */ border-bottom: 1px dotted;  cursor: help;}q:before, q:after { content: ''; }/*  */legend { color: #000; } /* for ie6 */fieldset, img { border: none; } /* img  *//* ：optgroup */button, input, select, textarea {    font-size: 100%; /*  */}/*  */table {  border-collapse: collapse;  border-spacing: 0;}/*  hr */hr {    border: none;    height: 1px;} .clear{ clear:both;} 
a:hover{text-decoration: none;}
#wrapper
{
    max-width:1920px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0px 0;
    background-color:#f8edcd;
    min-width:220px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 240px) 
{
    svg
    {
        height:150px;
        width:98%;
        margin:0px;
    }
    #msg_box 
    { 
        position: relative;
        width:98%;
        margin:0px;
    }
    #msg_title 
    {
        margin:0 auto;
        min-height:25px;
    }
    #msg_data
    {
        margin:15px auto 5px;
        height:150px;
        padding:2%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) and (min-width: 241px) 
{
    svg
    {
        height:204px;
        width:98%;
        margin:0px;
    }
    #msg_box 
    { 
        position: relative;
        width:98%;
        margin:0px;
    }
    #msg_title 
    {
        margin:0 auto;
        min-height:25px;
    }
    #msg_data
    {
        margin:15px auto 5px;
        height:170px;
        padding:2%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) and (min-width: 321px) 
{
    svg
    {
        height:256px;
        width:98%;
        margin:0px;
    }
    #msg_box 
    { 
        position: relative;
        width:98%;
        margin:0px;
    }
    #msg_title 
    {
        margin:0 auto;
        min-height:25px;
    }
    #msg_data
    {
        margin:15px auto 5px;
        height:168px;
        padding:2%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) and (min-width: 401px) 
{
    svg
    {
        height:310px;
        width:98%;
        margin:0px;
    }
    #msg_box 
    { 
        position: relative;
        width:98%;
        margin:0px;
    }
    #msg_title 
    {
        margin:0 auto;
        min-height:25px;
    }
    #msg_data
    {
        margin:15px auto 5px;
        height:190px;
        padding:2%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 568px) and (min-width: 481px) 
{
    svg
    {
        height:370px;
        width:98%;
        margin:0px;
    }
    #msg_box 
    { 
        position: relative;
        width:98%;
        margin:0px;
    }
    #msg_title 
    {
        margin:0 auto;
        min-height:25px;
    }
    #msg_data
    {
        margin:15px auto 5px;
        height:190px;
        padding:2%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 685px) and (min-width: 569px) 
{
    svg
    {
        height: 280px;
        float:left;
        width:64%;
    }
    #msg_box 
    { 
        float:left;
        position: relative;
        width:36%;
    }
    #msg_title 
    {
        width:80%;
        margin:0 auto;
        min-height:25px;
    }
    #msg_data
    {
        margin:15px auto 5px;
        width:90%;
        height:210px;
        padding:2%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 686px) 
{
    svg
    {
        height: 320px;
        float:left;
        width:64%;
    }
    #msg_box 
    { 
        float:left;
        position: relative;
        width:36%;
    }
    #msg_title 
    {
        width:80%;
        margin:0 auto;
        min-height:25px;
    }
    #msg_data
    {
        margin:15px auto 5px;
        width:90%;
        height:240px;
        padding:2%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 769px) 
{
    svg
    {
        height: 424px;
        float:left;
        width:64%;
    }
    #msg_box 
    { 
        float:left;
        position: relative;
        width:36%;
    }
    #msg_title 
    {
        width:80%;
        margin:0 auto;
        min-height:25px;
    }
    #msg_data
    {
        margin:15px auto 5px;
        width:90%;
        height:318px;
        padding:2%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) and (min-width: 1025px) 
{
    svg
    {
        height: 530px;
        float:left;
        width:64%;
    }
    #msg_box 
    { 
        float:left;
        position: relative;
        width:36%;
    }
    #msg_title 
    {
        width:80%;
        margin:0 auto;
        min-height:25px;
    }
    #msg_data
    {
        margin:15px auto 5px;
        width:90%;
        height:400px;
        padding:2%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1600px) and (min-width: 1281px) 
{
    svg
    {
        height: 674px;
        float:left;
        width:64%;
    }
    #msg_box 
    { 
        float:left;
        position: relative;
        width:36%;
    }
    #msg_title 
    {
        width:80%;
        margin:0 auto;
        min-height:25px;
    }
    #msg_data
    {
        margin:15px auto 5px;
        width:90%;
        height:506px;
        padding:2%;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1601px)
{
    svg
    {
        height: 842px;
        float:left;
        width:64%;
    }
    #msg_box 
    { 
        float:left;
        position: relative;
        width:36%;
    }
    #msg_title 
    {
        width:80%;
        margin:0 auto;
        min-height:25px;
    }
    #msg_data
    {
        margin:15px auto 5px;
        width:90%;
        height:632px;
        padding:2%;
    }
}

.tip{
    display:none;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #EBECED;
    color:#edeef0;
    font-weight: bold
    ;z-index:1000;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    /*gradient color*/
    background:#000;
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#494949', endColorstr='#656565'); /* IE6,IE7 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#494949', endColorstr='#656565')"; /* IE8 */ 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #494949,#656565); /* Firefox */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#494949), to(#656565));
    word-break:keep-all;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#msg_title {
    border:1px solid #999;
    font-weight:bold;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;      
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;   
    border-radius:8px;            
    box-shadow:1px 2px 4px #999;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 2px 4px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 2px 4px #999;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    font-size:21px;
    text-align: center;
    padding:10px;
    line-height: 25px;
    color:#333;
    /*gradient color*/
    background:#000;
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#dddddd'); /* IE6,IE7 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#dddddd')"; /* IE8 */ 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff,#dddddd); /* Firefox */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#dddddd));
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
#msg_data{
    line-height: 26px;
    background:#e5e5e5;
    border:1px solid #999; 
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;      
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;  
    border-radius:6px; 
    box-shadow:1px 2px 8px #999;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 2px 8px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 2px 8px #999;
    overflow: auto;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    font-size:18px;
    text-align: left;   
    color:#333;
    /*gradient color*/
    background:#000;
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#dddddd'); /* IE6,IE7 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#dddddd')"; /* IE8 */ 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff,#dddddd); /* Firefox */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#dddddd));

body {background-color:#b0c4de;}
}
```

n Internet Explorer, the map is large is my page is nearly correct except that the map is not to the left, it is below the state listings:

[image]

### Update

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vxNpF/4/) with selfcontained example of problem, I believe what is happening is that my CSS is shadowing itself.

### Update 2

I've managed to take it from scratch and resize the map but I don't fuly understand why doubling the last two parameters of the `viewBox`attribute actually makes the map smaller. What I'm getting now is starting to look acceptable:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you want to set the `viewBox="…"` attribute for your SVG to bound your content, and then scale the SVG element as you wish.

### Demos

- http://jsfiddle.net/Jq3gy/5/
- http://jsfiddle.net/Jq3gy/2/

<sub>Note that I have a copyright-free optimized US SVG map available: http://phrogz.net/SVG/USMap.svg</sub>

Comment: I've tried this `<svg width="100%" heigth="100%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 540 360" xml:space="preserve">` but it's not working.

Comment: Ok here is the fiddle with the problem http://jsfiddle.net/vxNpF/3/  I think what is happening is CSS shadowing the variables. I try to make a selfcontained fiddle with the problem and here with the link. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I'm sorry, perhaps I should have been more explicit: you should create a pared-down test case. Delete your irrelevant markup and CSS (which is most of it). If you can delete a line or word and the problem remains, then you haven't pared it down enough.

Comment: Ok, I'm paring it down and will update a fiddle with the problem. THank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is setting the height to 674px (on my screen at least) and width to 64% of it's parent container (#mapcontainer).  This turns out to be a tall and narrow shape.  The browser is scaling the map to fit in that narrow container, which is what is making it look tiny (on Chrome at least).

Try the following:

- Work out why #mapcontainer is not using all the available space.
- Ensure #mapcontainer has a similar aspect ratio to the SVG viewBox (540:360).
- Don't try to change the width and height of the SVG, just leave it at 100% and let it fill its container.
- It's possible you might have more luck embedding the SVG using an `<object>` element.  Rather than using inline SVG.  If all else fails, try that.